# Creating a redshift table ddl to match parquet file

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift, parquet

I have some parquet files that I would like to push into redshift.  I am not too familiar with parquet schema, but I've used the parquet-tools schema cli command to get the column names.  This has worked for some of the parquets I have, as I've been able to successfully copy command those into redshift tables I set up using the schema I got from using: parquet-tools schema.

However, I am running into trouble creating the appropriate table to house data from parquets when the parquet has "repeated group list".  Everything I've tried has resulted in the copy command failing, so any help would be appreciated, thanks!  Here is the output for my parquet file schema:

```
 message spark_schema {
  optional binary guid (UTF8);
  optional binary orgName (UTF8);
  optional binary isOrgAuthoritative (UTF8);
  optional binary degree (UTF8);
  optional binary degreeGuid (UTF8);
  optional binary graduationDate (UTF8);
  optional group academicHonors (LIST) {
    repeated group list {
      optional group element {
        optional binary honor (UTF8);
        optional binary honorGuid (UTF8);
        optional binary startDate (UTF8);
        optional binary endDate (UTF8);
        optional binary isStartDateComputed (UTF8);
        optional binary isEndDateComputed (UTF8);
        optional binary reportedDate (UTF8);
      }
    }
  }
  optional binary startDate (UTF8);
  optional binary endDate (UTF8);
  optional binary isStartDateComputed (UTF8);
  optional binary isEndDateComputed (UTF8);
  optional binary reportedDate (UTF8);
}
```

Comment: have you tried using glue crawler to do this for you?

Comment: @JonScott yah but that will give me an array, which redshift does not support.  Redshift also will not let me selectively copy only specified columns, splitting that data set above into 2 or more tables.  I suppose I could create an external table on a redshift spectrum cluster, but other than that, kind of stumped on this one.

Comment: @nkramer52 did you find out any solution ?

Comment: @Anvay unfortunately, no.